# Why "renkontiĝo" is more common than "renkonto" for saying "a meeting"?

Tags: etymology

*Renkonti* is a transitive verb. For speaking about the act or the event of meeting, it would be shorter to use *Renkonto* instead of *Renkontiĝo*. Why is the word second more common?

Comment: Have you got any figures on how frequent the words are in a corpus of texts?

Comment: @OliverMason I have tried both on tekstaro, but both had more than 100 results, so I don't have precise metrics. On Google "Esperanta renkonto" has 564 results while "Esperanta renkontiĝo" has 4 290 results.

Comment: In the Tekstaro: 473 for *renkontiĝo* and 123 for *renkonto.*

Answer (score 4):

Simply put, we can say *multaj personoj renkontiĝas* - and that is a *renkontiĝo*.

Of course *renkonto* is a valid word with a similar meaning, but it doesn't have this same feeling as the act done by people who *renkontiĝas*.

Answer (score 2):

In English, you can write *We met in London* as a complete sentence. In Esperanto, however, the verb *renkonti* is transitive, so *Ni renkontis* ("We met...") feels incomplete on its own: it is more complete as *Ni renkontis nin* or *Ni renkontis unu la alian.*

Otherwise, we can make the verb intransitive: *renkontiĝi* ("to be met, to meet (each other), to encounter"). Then the sentence is complete in the form *Ni renkontiĝis en Londono.*

Looking at the nouns, *renkonto* is a single encounter between two people or two groups, while *renkontiĝo* is vaguer, possibly referring to many people or sets of people in a process. That is why the latter is much more often used for the names of Esperanto events.